# config.properties file with multiple urls

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a configuration file with multiple url's and needs to be sent depending on test scenario.
But in one scenario the url is being sent and in another it is not. Please suggest the change

Tried modifying the names , loops but could not find the correct solution. 
[image]

the TPurl property is being returned as null either while running as testNG suite or as an individual test.

Comment: Please edit your question, remove the code screenshot and include the actual code in your post itself. Also its not clear as to which is your test method. So please add more details.

Comment: Sorry for that , I'm novice to Selenium and these forums .... spent almost a day to figure out to post my code but due to challenges I was limited to post only this much snippet. The issue is resolved , thanks for reaching out.